Validating a signed catalog file using BCryptVerifySignature
I'm trying to validate that a catalog file (.cat) has not been tampered with.
The idea is to sign it with the private key from Self Signed Certificate on the sender side and validate it on the receiver side with "BCryptVerifySignature" from the windows api and a certificate.
WinVerifyTrust can do it, but it seams that it requires that I install the certificate in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and I'm trying to avoid that.
I'm on the right track or have I completely misunderstood BCryptVerifySignature, WinVerifyTrust and/or the signing of catalog files.
The following code is me trying to use BCryptVerifySignature but it fails with STATUS_INVALID_SIGNATURE.
//
// Load Certificate
//
std::ifstream certFile;
certFile.open(L"test.cer", ::std::ios::binary);
std::string certificateData((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(certFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;    
PCCERT_CONTEXT context = ::CertCreateCertificateContext(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(certificateData.data()),
    static_cast<DWORD>(certificateData.size())
);
::CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    &context->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_SIGN_KEY_FLAG,
    NULL,
    &hKey
);

//
// Load catalog file
//
DWORD encoding{};
DWORD contentType{};
DWORD formatType{};
HCERTSTORE storeHandle{};
HCRYPTMSG msg{};

::CryptQueryObject(
    CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE
    , L"test.cat"
    , CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED
    , CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY
    , 0
    , &encoding
    , &contentType
    , &formatType
    , &storeHandle
    , &msg
    , NULL
);

//
// Get singer info from catalog file to get encrypted hash
//
DWORD signerSize = 0;
::CryptMsgGetParam(msg, CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 0, nullptr, &signerSize);
std::vector<BYTE> signerData(signerSize);
::CryptMsgGetParam(msg, CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 0, signerData.data(), &signerSize);
auto signerInfo = reinterpret_cast<CMSG_SIGNER_INFO*>(signerData.data());

//
// Get catalog content to hash
// Not sure if this is the correct data to do the hash on for use in BCryptVerifySignature
//
DWORD contentSize = 0;
::CryptMsgGetParam(msg, CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM, 0, nullptr, &contentSize);
std::vector<BYTE> contentData(contentSize);
::CryptMsgGetParam(msg, CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM, 0, contentData.data(), &contentSize);

//
// Hash catalog content
//
BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE phAlgorithm = NULL;
BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE phHash = NULL;
DWORD hashObjSize{};
DWORD hashSize{};
DWORD resultSize{};
std::vector<BYTE> hashObj;
std::vector<BYTE> hash;
BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&phAlgorithm, BCRYPT_SHA256_ALGORITHM, nullptr, 0);
BCryptGetProperty(phAlgorithm, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&hashObjSize), sizeof(hashObjSize), &resultSize, 0);
hashObj.resize(hashObjSize);
BCryptGetProperty(phAlgorithm, BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&hashSize, sizeof(DWORD), &resultSize, 0);
hash.resize(hashSize);
BCryptCreateHash(phAlgorithm, &phHash, hashObj.data(), hashObjSize, NULL, 0, 0);
BCryptHashData(phHash, contentData.data(), hashSize, 0);
BCryptFinishHash(phHash, hash.data(), hashSize, 0);

//
// Validate
//
BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO PKCS1PaddingInfo = { 0 };
PKCS1PaddingInfo.pszAlgId = L"SHA256";
auto rValue = BCryptVerifySignature(
    hKey,
    &PKCS1PaddingInfo,
    hash.data(),
    hashSize,
    signerInfo->EncryptedHash.pbData,
    signerInfo->EncryptedHash.cbData,
    BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1
);

// returns STATUS_INVALID_SIGNATURE

Creating the signed catalog file with powershell:
New-FileCatalog -CatalogFilePath test.cat -CatalogVersion 2.0 -Path .

$params = @{
    Type = 'Custom' 
    CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My'
    Subject = 'CN=TEST'
    TextExtension = @('2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3')
    HashAlgorithm = 'sha256'
    KeySpec = 'Signature'
    KeyUsage = 'DigitalSignature'
    KeyAlgorithm = 'RSA'
    KeyLength = 2048
    NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(100)
}
New-SelfSignedCertificate @params

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password1234" -Force -AsPlainText
$path = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\" + $cert.thumbprint
Export-PfxCertificate -cert $path -FilePath test.pfx -Password $pwd
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath test.cer

$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath test.pfx
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath test.cat -Certificate $cert -HashAlgorithm SHA256

